# Dell Vostro 3450 Bluetooth disables on reboot

Tags: 11.04, dell, bluetooth

I have a dell Vostro 3450 with an Core i3 CPU and no additional graphics card. The problem is, when I shut down and start later, Compiz is always disabled. After I do a reboot (not shutdown and power on, that doesn't help) Bluetooth works.

So practically I have to turn on and then reboot to get everything going, also there seems to be a problem with keyboard light. On power on it is always turned to the second level of brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Dell Vostro 3450, but on my Dell Vostro 3350 I solved this problem with [this guide](http://www.edwardcrosby.com/2011/06/17/bluetooth-fix-in-linux-mint-11ubuntu-11-04/) and so bluetooth works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It happens with my USB bluetooth with Ubuntu 11.04. With openSUSE 11.4, It doesn't happen (with 11.3 it still happens) I don't know why (maybe 'cause some packages)

I would like to talk to you about this notebook. I want to buy one and I need to know about compatibility with Ubuntu/Mint and openSUSE. I think I'll buy a simple version (Core i3 CPU and no additional graphics card) like yours.

Could you talk to me a little about your experience with this notebook and Linux?

Thank you so much!